# If $G$ is profinite and $M$ finite abelian, must there exist an open subgroup $H\le G$ with $H^2(H,M) = 0$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a profinite group, and $M$ a finite abelian group with trivial $G$-action. Must there exist an open subgroup $H\le G$ with $H^2(H,M) = 0$?

Comment: No ($G=\mathbf{Z}_p^2$, $M=\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$).

Comment: @YCor Ah I suppose that's because $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ is isomorphic to each of its open subgroups?

Comment: @YCor Okay but it IS true that every element of $H^2(G,M)$ vanishes over some open subgroup $H\le_o G$ right?

Comment: No (same example).

Comment: @YCor Isn't every class in $H^2(G,M)$ represented by a continuous cocycle $z : G^2\rightarrow M$ such that $z(1,G) = z(G,1) = 0$? By continuity $z^{-1}(0)$ is open, and contains $(1,1)$, and hence by the definition of the topology on $G\times G$, $z^{-1}(0)$ must contain an open subgroup of $G\times G$, which must in turn contain $H\times H$ for some $H\le_o G$?

Comment: @rtz, your argument seems fine as far as it goes, but it doesn't follow that $H^2(H,M)=0$.  I think all you did is show that there's always an open subgroup so that the restriction map $H^2(G,M)\to H^2(H,M)$ is zero.

Comment: @HJRW I don't think I've even showed that much. I've only showed that for every $z\in H^2(G,M)$, it is zero on some open subgroup $H$. Since $G$ is not assumed to be finitely generated, $H^2(G,M)$ might be infinite. But anyway, this is all I wanted to show after I realized that the question in the OP had a negative answer.